# Заполнение поля id, которые свободны

Tags: python, django, sqlite3

Можно ли сделать так,чтобы при добавлении статьи в бд sqlite3 `id` присваивался с начало, которые свободные (например если удалим статью с `id = 1` то он уже не используется?)

Comment: Обычно переиспользовать айдишники почти всегда оказывается плохой идеей. Да и удалять насовсем что-то, у чего есть айдишник из идущего подряд диапазона, - тоже не очень хорошая практика. Обычно в таких случаях строки не удаляются, а просто помечаются как скрытые.

Comment: В чем проблема добавить флаг del ?

Comment: Это плохая идея, ибо как минимум эффективность такого подхода хромает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, учту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обобщу ответы из комментариев.

Вообще это возможно, но только в том случае, если ключевое поле `id` не является автоинкрементным (присваивается не автоматически, а указывается напрямую) и вы сами будите следить за его уникальностью. Однако, если учесть тег `django`, то таких способов в голову не приходит, так как `id` по-умолчанию в данном фреймворке являются автоинкрементами (хотя и там тоже возможно указывать ключи вручную).

С другой стороны, как верно подметили в коментах к вопросу, это совершенно не нужно с практической точки зрения. Куда правильнее помечать записи неиспользуемыми.